# Gradle runIdea task opens too old version

Tags: java, gradle

My XText plugin requires second Intellij IDEA window to be run. It is done by Gradle runIdea task, but it downloaded and runs Intellij IDEA 15.0.

I would like to know how can i set gradle to open latest IDE version(2016.2 that i have already installed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *.idea module of your project there is `build.gradle` where should be a property which is called `ideaVersion`, which in turn sets the version of IDE to use. You can modify this prop f.ex. to

```
ideaVersion = '162.1812.8'
```

Comment: It was set to 143.381.42 for some reason. Thanks a lot!